# How do i get the sum of fields in mongodb?

Tags: javascript

I have created the pipeline which will find the sum of the field I want but I just cant find a way to execute it in the node js project and get the sum as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ $sum: [ <expression1>, <expression2>] }
```